# How can I use the command line to search multiple files for a block of code and count its occurances?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a project directory containing multiple subdirectories and files. Some of these files repeat the same blocks of code (functions that are defined multiples times). Sometimes many times these functions share the same name but have different definitions.

One of my goals is to find all of the instances where a function has been defined with the same name. I am able to do this with my text editor, grep, and ripgrep by searching for just the line declaring a function, like `def set_name`.

After getting those instances, my second goal is to compare their method definitions and so that I can later determine what to do with the functions that were declared using the same name but contain a different block of code from what they should have.

What I think I need to do is search for entire blocks of code but I'm stuck by not knowing how to search files for multiple lines because neither my text editor not grep allow this - and ripgrep has not yet released the `--multiline` feature.

What I know is the name of the function and what the function should look like. What I need to find is where other functions have been declared with the same name, but are different. I'll need to find what those functions are, and how many occurrences there are (there will be many repeats).

Say the function I want to search for is called `say_hi` and it should look like this:

```
def say_hi(name)
  return "Hi, #{name}!"
end
```

I want to find all the functions in the project folder that basically start with `def say_hi(name)` and end with `end` but don't contain exactly `return "Hi, #{name}!"` as the block of code in the middle.

I've been using grep to find the first two lines of a code block where a function is declared with the same name, but the second line is not what it should be:

```
grep 'def say_hi(name)' -A 2 -nr directory | grep -v 'return "Hi #{name}!"'
```

For the most part, this works and I'm getting occurrences where line 1 is the same and line 2 is something else. I'd like to know how to count these occurrences to later help me find all the variations. Is this even a good way to go about it or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Try to use `wc -l`. It will tell you the count.

Comment: I am thinking you would need at least a rudimentary parser that ignored differences in comments and white space.

Comment: I feel it's easier if you just find each occurrence of the function, give it some random input, and compare the output. If the output is the same across the functions for multiple different input, you can reasonably assume they are the same.

Comment: @pkqxdd it would be immensely difficult to write a tool that can figure out (and handle) what types of values to pass as the args to every function along with the type of output and the type of return code, and two functions outputing the same thing doesn't come close to meaning they're the same functions (consider for example `if (x>1) print "ERR"` vs `if (x>2) print "ERR"` passed the arg `x=3`).

Comment: Finding a block of code and replacing it is asked and answered at  [Replace one block of text with another block of text when replacement text is in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281942/56041)

Answer (score 3):

if your functions are always as simple as you show, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
def foo(name)
  return "Hi, #{name}!"
end

def bar(name)
  return "Hi, #{name}!"
end
```

then you can do something like this to normalize white space and print each function as a single line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^def / { fn=""; inFn=1 }
inFn    { fn=(fn == "" ? "" : fn ORS) $0 }
/^end$/ { prt(); inFn=0 }

function prt() {
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",fn)
    print fn
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
def foo(name) return "Hi, #{name}!" end
def bar(name) return "Hi, #{name}!" end
```

and then run a plain old diff between files or

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort | uniq -c
      1 def bar(name) return "Hi, #{name}!" end
      1 def foo(name) return "Hi, #{name}!" end

$ awk -f tst.awk file | grep '^def foo *(' | sort | uniq -c
      1 def foo(name) return "Hi, #{name}!" end
```

or similar to find single/multiple occurrences of all or individual functions (yes you could do the equivalent to that in one awk script too but this approach separates identifying/normalizing functions from what you want to do with them).

Obviously that is not a parser so if you need to strip comments, for example, then you'd have to figure out how to separate comments from similar text within strings, etc. and it'll compress/change white space within strings just like it will between tokens so it isn't (and cannot be) precise but it might be good enough for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could I do this on an entire directory of files rather than a single file?

Comment: Of course. Why not just try it?

Comment: Neat approach - I salute you - again!

Comment: @EdMorton, unfortunately, this isn't working for me with the files that I need to normal white space in. If I create simple files like your example, it works perfectly but the files I'm working with contain more than just methods starting with `def` and ending with `end`. There are classes and comments that I think may be throwing off that tst.awk file. The difficulty for me is that these methods can be found in many unconventional files throughout the project directory. Some could be in an ERB file, some could be defined in a HAML file.

Comment: You can't expect to parse general code without a parser for the language that code is written in. Any kind of pattern matching tool like you're asking for can only work on a subset of code that fits specific patterns and you'd have to provide a sample of all of that to stand any chance of getting such a tool to work. All I had to go on was the code segment you provided so, obviously, files that contains text that looks like that is what the tool works on. Hence the first sentence in my answer `if your functions are always as simple as you show`